# Animation in videos

Tags: video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Animation in video](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/animation-in-video)

I know this is a photography forum but maybe someone can help me with a video related question?

I have a video of a guy doing push ups. On that video I want to be able to draw some lines showing what angles the arms should be at when the guy is down and up. The lines should follow the guy on screen as he doing the exercise to show the viewers the correct way of doing the exercise.

Can anyone suggest any software that i will be able to use to achieve this effect? I have looked at some Final Cut Pro stuff but it is unclear if I can draw primitives (lines, circles etc.) with this package on screen?

Again, sorry if this is the wrong forum to ask. Hopefully someone out there have done something similar to this in the past and can point me in the right direction

Comment: @vivek_jonam - please be careful suggesting other sites. It could lead to the question being reposted when it should be migrated.

Comment: Yip, like I said I know this was the wrong place to ask...Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though